# Bad request 400 on sending xml request in wcf rest

Tags: wcf, rest

I am writing a sample application using wcf rest for authentication. Here is the snapshot of the code:

**service Interface:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAuthenticate
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/VUser",RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Xml ), ]
    string CreateUser(VUser user);
}
```

Datacontract class:

```
[DataContract]
public class VUser
{
    public VUser()
    {
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string NickName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string lName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string fName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

**Service class:**

```
public class Authenticate : IAuthenticate
{

    #region IAuthenticate members
    public string CreateUser(Vuser user)
    {
        //processing xml for response

    }
    #endregion IAuthenticate
}
```

**client code:**

```
       Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000");

        using (WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Authenticate), baseAddress))
        {
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate");
            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();

        }
```

Now I am using fiddler to send the request after host.open() and send the the request has shown:

post http://localhost:8000/Vuser/

User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:8000
content-length: 233
content-type: text/xml

and in request body :

sandy
r
sunil
sunil.r
919900101948
winter
male
01

but it is returning me HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request. My question is am I passing the vuser class correctly to the create user method or is there any other way to send the vuser.

Please help me.

Comment: Please check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372335/what-is-the-correct-uri-for-sending-parameters-via-post-in-wcf-rest-services

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with serialization.

Serialization uses the default consrtuctor, without parameters.

In C# the compiler will automatically create a default constructor, **except** if you create a constructor with a parameter.

The Authenticate class is missing a default constructor, you will therefore have probelms sending it over WCF.

Comment: hi shiraz i created a default constructor as well but it is still the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Kindly specify The Datacontract Namespace in DataContract Class

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/Service.svc")]

and follow same in Xml file

Answer (score 0):

The Namespace in both client and server should match. Try to add namespace name as

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://sample.com")]
public class VUser
```

in the server contract. And then make sure the xml string has the xmlns value with the same namespace

```
"<VUser xmlns=\"http://sample.com" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">...</VUser>"
```